# How can I locate and remove an application in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: uninstall

I'm new to Ubuntu. I would like to know how to locate a certain software application and remove it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you want to remove and why - what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I wanted to remove a package called wine , I did it thanks to soupy's answer .

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it on the command line:

Open up your terminal, and run `dpgk -l | grep $APPNAME`, where `$APPNAME' is the name of the application you are looking for. This searches all of the packages installed on your computer.

The package names are listed in the second column. Pick the one you want to remove, then run `sudo apt-get remove $PACKAGE_NAME`, with the appropriate name substituted to remove the application.

Answer (score 0):

With Ubuntu **16.04** you need to open up the **Software center** and click on installed, it will display a list of all the application you have installed on your system just click on the ones you want to remove and it will be removed